# Windows Mobile WinInet library working with HTTP compresion

Tags: windows-mobile, compression, wininet

On Windows Mobile metod InternetSetOption http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms918381.aspx does not support option `INTERNET_OPTION_HTTP_DECODING` is there some simple method to turn on compresion under WM 6.0 or any external library that will decompress content received by WinInet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no mechanism to just "turn decompression on" - it's simply not supported by wininet under CE. Since the server is very likely going to use the [deflate algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEFLATE) you can manually decomress the data with something like [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) ([which OpenNETCF provides a CE port of](http://www.opennetcf.com/zlibce) for free).